# Testcafe how to get the count of something to use outside of an expect

Tags: testing, automated-tests, expect, e2e-testing, testcafe

```
test('Check on the individual devices stuff', async t => {
    const devices = monitoredDevicesSection.find('.card');
    console.log(devices);
    console.log(devices.count);
    console.log(await devices.count);
    await t.expect(devices.count).eql(10);
});
```

Alrighty -- using [testcafe](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/) I'm trying to figure out how to get my hands on the count of something, outside of an expect.

In the above code, the test passes because there are in fact 10 things with class .card there.

BUT, I can't even assign a variable/console.log anything and get '10'

The above console.log (the last one) will always print 0.

I feel like I've tried all manners and orderings of awaits and what not.. and I simply can't get
const actualCount = 
console.log(actualCount) to print 10.

Thoughts?  I know I must be right on the edge of getting this right hah.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the following test: https://github.com/MarinaRukavitsyna/TestCafe---How-to-log-elements-count-to-Console/blob/master/index_test.js. Would you please update it so that I can see the issue locally?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rstudner/87480e672593292922f124ac8889370e

So with the t.expect commented out, I get 0.
If I use the t.expect, I get 10.

Does it not work with functional Selectors?

Comment: Well, it isn't due to the expect.  I modified your code to use a .find and it works fine.  Must be something about my page.  I have to do that expect 'song and dance' or I always get 0 instead of 10.

Comment: Would you please share your complete test (with a link to your web page) so that I can check and research the issue locally?

Comment: I figured out the issue, basically.  The data on the page I'm hoping to find loads async.  So my .find, at one moment, is in fact factually zero.

By having the expects on my .count, it is simply waiting until it is 'truthy' (data has loaded and > "falsy 0") -- which then of course lets me get out a count > 0.

The only thing I have left to figure out is there is a spinner div... that goes away when data is loaded to then show the .card's.  But, if I wait for the spinner div to be "notOk", there is still a tiny window where .card is also length 0.

Comment: The .count returns a promise (because the proxy has to interact with the actual DOM). If you use .expect it will pass the promise to the expect function that will perform the await. If you are using it outside an expect, you will have to add it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If you add an await I believe it should take a [snapshot](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#dom-node-snapshot) of the dom so that you can console.log the count. Hopefully that will work out for you

`const devices = await monitoredDevicesSection.find('.card');`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue time ago (leave here the answer for google search):

```
function select(selector){
    return Selector(selector).with({boundTestRun:testController})
}

const devices= select('.card');
const devices_count = await devices.count
```